# How to use ReactDOM.render inside a loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to calculate the height of a component before it is previewed to the user. I found the following method online :

```
const measureElement = element => {
  // Creates the hidden div appended to the document body
  const container = document.getElementById('temporal-root')

  // Renders the React element into the hidden div
  ReactDOM.render(element, container)

  // Gets the element size
  const height = container.clientHeight
  const width = container.clientWidth

  return { height, width }

  return { height: 0, width: 0 }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
  highlightsMemoized.forEach(section => {
        const sectionHeight =
          measureElement(
            <ComponentSection
              section={section}
              style={{ width: '350px' }}
            />
          ).height 
        
      })
```

The problem is that `height` has always the same value, which is the one of the latest item in the loop. Is there a way to get the correct height pf each item using this approach?

Comment: Have you tried `map` instead?

Comment: I have used a similar technique before to create a grid with dynamic row heights, with virtualization. Its important that your container and element css are correct to facilitate what you are expecting to happen. Render the measure container and element to the screen, and inspect it to see that is is in fact what you expect it to be.

Comment: Can you please share some resources for that? I already did what you mentioned =/ . In fact I tested the code with 1, 2 and 3 items, and it always shows the same result, which is getting the same height (of the latest item in the array )